# Laravel + Selenium + Integrated : Extends Selenium

Tags: php, laravel, selenium

I'm working with Selenium and Laravel 5.1

I am testing with Selenium with the great extension Integrated, but it seems to do basic stuff, but it doesn't do evertything Selenium does.

My problem is I can't find very well a way to extend it, I don't really get it how does it work. Most of selenium docs are in JS, and I need PHP.

When I open file Selenium.php in Integrated package, I don't really see what is the bridge between PHP and Selenium.

My main issue right now is I must deal with autocomplete field.

So, user should enter a CP number, wait 2 sec, and clic an autocomplete list ( < li >item< /li > )

I saw a lot of docs about selenium + autocomplete fields, but I don't actually understand how to apply it to Laravel..

Any idea that can help???

Comment: You should look into Codeception I utilize it for quite a few laravel projects.

Comment: it means stop using phpunit?

Comment: No codeception is built on PHPUnit

Comment: It just adds a lot more functionality like built in integration with Selenium

Comment: ohh, so I should stop using Integrated package, and use Codeception for my Acceptance test?

Comment: should you? that I don't know depends on your use case. Can you? yes. You can integrate it straight into Laravel if you do some searching online you can find some instructions on how to do so.

Comment: it worked using codeception for acceptance test, please put your comment as answer! Tx!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option I have used in the past to deal with this type of situation is Codeception. It is also built on PHPUnit and can be pretty tightly integrated in to Laravel. It is also already setup out of the box to work with Selenium.